# Retrofit2 Replacing query parameters

Tags: android, retrofit2, url-encoding, okhttp

I am using `Retrofit2` and sending request with input parameters as follows. But retrofit automatically converts **+** symbol to **%2B**. How to encode this and send as **+** itself

Relevant code

**1)** *Interface*

```
@POST("/registrationapi.php")
    Call<RegistrationPOJO> registrationResponse(@Query("firstname") String firstname , @Query("lastname") String lastname,
                                                @Query("email") String email, @Query("password") String password,
                                                @Query("uid") String uid, @Query("mobile") String mobile,
                                                @Query("key") String key
    );
```

**2)** *RestClient*

```
private APIInterface service;

public RestClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfiguration.BASEURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
    }
public void getRegistrationInfo(final Registration context, String firstname, String lastname, String email,
                                    String password, String uid, String mobile, String key
                                    ){
        Call<RegistrationPOJO> reg =service.registrationResponse(firstname,lastname,email,password,uid,mobile,key);
        reg.enqueue(
                new Callback<RegistrationPOJO>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationPOJO> call, Response<RegistrationPOJO> response) {
                        success = response.isSuccessful();

                        if(success) {

                            //Handle success flow 
                        } else {
                            //Handle error flow 
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationPOJO> call, Throwable t) {
                        //Handle error flow 
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

> My mobile number is having `+` symbol at the beginning. From the
>   retrofit logs, I can see this is converted like
>   `mobile=%2B11111111111` while sending the request.
>
> I am expecting encoding and making input parameter like
>   `mobile=+11111111111`

*Corresponding gradle dependencies are*

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

---

As per anurag's suggestion. I have changed parameter to

```
@Query(value = "mobile" , encoded=true) String mobile
```

and its working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `encoded = true` in query params.

```
Call<ResponseBody> method(@Query(value = "+11111111111", encoded = true) String mobile) {
        .....
      }
```

Comment: How do I modify this statement according to your answer? RestClient().getRegistrationInfo(this,firstname,lastname,email,password,uid,mobile,key);  Moreover is this hardcoding possible? As Call will be in interfce

Comment: @Stallion Did the above solution of encoded = true worked or not?

Comment: @Stallion At this moment I am setting up my system as my my previous laptop is damaged. Try using @Query("firstname", encoded = true ) String firstname

Comment: Thanks man, It worked.. Ive modified like this in Interface  @Query(value = "mobile" , encoded=true) String mobile